# Debugging C++ extension for Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, windows-10, 64-bit

I have a problem when I try to debug my C++ extension for Python.
The error is
**Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread**

I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio) and it works when I run in the release version.

Python code:

```
from itertools import islice
from random import random
from time import perf_counter

COUNT = 500000  # Change this value depending on the speed of your computer
DATA = list(islice(iter(lambda: (random() - 0.5) * 3.0, None), COUNT))

e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527

def sinh(x):
    return (1 - (e ** (-2 * x))) / (2 * (e ** -x))

def cosh(x):
    return (1 + (e ** (-2 * x))) / (2 * (e ** -x))

def tanh(x):
    tanh_x = sinh(x) / cosh(x)
    return tanh_x

def sequence_tanh(data):
    '''Applies the hyperbolic tangent function to map all values in
    the sequence to a value between -1.0 and 1.0.
    '''
    result = []
    for x in data:
        result.append(tanh(x))
    return result

def test(fn, name):
    start = perf_counter()
    result = fn(DATA)
    duration = perf_counter() - start
    print('{} took {:.3f} seconds\n\n'.format(name, duration))

    for d in result:
        assert -1 <= d <=1, " incorrect values"

from superfastcode import fast_tanh
if __name__ == "__main__":
   test(lambda d: [fast_tanh(x) for x in d], '[fast_tanh(x) for x in d]')
```

C++ code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <cmath>

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

PyObject* tanh_impl(PyObject *, PyObject* o) {
    double x = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
    double tanh_x = sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(tanh_x);
}

static PyMethodDef superfastcode_methods[] = {
    // The first property is the name exposed to Python, fast_tanh, the second is the C++
    // function name that contains the implementation.
    { "fast_tanh", (PyCFunction)tanh_impl, METH_O, nullptr },

    // Terminate the array with an object containing nulls.
{ nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};

static PyModuleDef superfastcode_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "superfastcode",                        // Module name to use with Python import statements
    "Provides some functions, but faster",  // Module description
    0,
    superfastcode_methods                   // Structure that defines the methods of the module
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_superfastcode() {
    return PyModule_Create(&superfastcode_module);
}
```

I am using the 64 bit version of Python 3.6, and are building the C++ code in x64 mode. Visual Studio 2017 15.6.4

I am linking with C:\Python\Python36.x64\libs\python36_d.lib and including header files from C:\Python\Python36.x64\include
My Python interpreter is in C:\Python\Python36.x64\

I get this result when I run the release build

```
[fast_tanh(x) for x in d] took 0.067 seconds
```

**Update**: I got it running in Py x86 but not x64.
When I hit the break point and step over (F10) it throws an exception.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that already the smallest amount of code required to trigger the error?

Comment: in your `if __name__ == '__main':` test you don't actually do anything and unconditionally just run the test. Is that intentional or did you just forget to indent the test code?

Comment: Indents fixed to make it concreate

Comment: I tried to follow the guide again and managed to get it running with Py 3.6 Win32 (x86)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution from Steve Dower @ Microsoft:
This looks more like a mismatch between debug binaries and release headers.

The guide you've referenced is designed to always use the release binaries of Python, even if you are building a debug extension. So either you should be linking against python36.lib/python36.dll, or ignoring most of the setting changes listed in the guide and linking against python36_d.lib/python36_d.dll (the linking should be automatic once you set the paths - the choice of C runtime library will determine whether debug/release Python is used).

Reference: [PTVS issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/3989#issuecomment-378116892)